# jQuery não encontra td gerado por Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma tabela dinâmica alimentada via Ajax que devolve o seguinte código através de um `foreach`:

```
<tr> 
    <td hidden value='{$conteudo['contId']}' id='contId'>
        {$conteudo['contId']}
    </td>
    <td> 
        {$conteudo['contNome']}
    </td>
    <td class='elementoNaDireita' >
        <button class='btn btn-outline btnExcluiArquivo'onclick='excluiArquivo();' name='btnExcluiArquivo' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalExcluiArquivo'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove btnExcluiArquivo'>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

E a função `excluiArquivo()` é essa:

```
function excluiArquivo(){   
    var contId = $('td:first', $(this).parents('tr')).text(); 
    console.log(contId);
    // document.getElementById('contId').value = contId;
    $("#contId").val(contId);

}
```

Por algum motivo a variável `contId` não recebe o valor da tag `<td>`, não recebe nada.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Não deu em nada! O intrigante é que na mesma página tenho uma tabela que possui essa mesma lógica e funciona, só que nessa que é devolvida pelo ajax não funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acontece que o `$(this)` na função não referencia o elemento clicado porque não é uma função do evento disparado `onclick`.

O que deveria fazer era enviar o elemento clicado através de um parâmetro `this`:

```
onclick='excluiArquivo(this);'
```

E na função receber esse valor:

```
function excluiArquivo(e){
                       ↑
```

E colocar um `.trim()` após `.text()` para eliminar os espaços gerados pelo HTML:

```
.text().trim()
```

Ficará assim:

```js
function excluiArquivo(e){
    var contId = $('td:first', $(e).parents('tr')).text().trim(); 
    console.log(contId);
    // document.getElementById('contId').value = contId;
    $("#contId").val(contId);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr> 
    <td hidden value='{$conteudo['contId']}' id='contId'>
        {$conteudo['contId']}
    </td>
    <td> 
        {$conteudo['contNome']}
    </td>
    <td class='elementoNaDireita' >
        <button class='btn btn-outline btnExcluiArquivo' onclick='excluiArquivo(this);' name='btnExcluiArquivo' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalExcluiArquivo'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove btnExcluiArquivo'>Apagar</span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

> Outra coisa: não coloque `id` no elemento:

```
<td hidden value='{$conteudo['contId']}' id='contId'>
                                         ↑↑
```

Porque você estará duplicando esse `id` no laço, e repetir id's é incorreto no HTML. Pode trocar por `class` se esse atributo tiver realmente alguma utilidade:

```
<td hidden value='{$conteudo['contId']}' class='contId'>
```

> Outra:

Essa linha `$("#contId").val(contId);` não faz sentido, porque esse elemento é uma `td` e não recebe valor via `.val()`.

Comment: Muito obrigado! teste aqui, deu tudo certo agora